# ViewPager is empty after replace transaction of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, android-viewpager

| btn1 | btn2 | btn3 | btn4 |

=---------------------------=

```
 Container
```

=---------------------------=

Hi there,
i'm having 4 buttons which make fragment transaction to a view pager fragment.

first click on the buttons everything works fine, second click causes view pager to be empty although all values in the adapter are correct but container is empty (offset pages are empty but if i'm swiping it create the other pages correctly!)

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

for the view pager adapter didn't work out. and the option :

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

is to create all pages from the beginning which cannot be done as we need to save some of the views and the pages.

the ONLY solution I have in my mind is to run on all current page and the offset:

```
mAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, mPager.getCurrentItem());
mAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager, mPager.getCurrentItem() + i );
```

Is there a clean and nice solution to solve this issue?

Thanks very much for the help